# Delete from one index element to another in a list

Tags: list, indexing, prolog

I need to delete from one element index to another in a list. So it should look like:

```
?-delm(2,4,[5,6,-3,6,11,56,81],L),write(L),nl.
L = [5,11,56,81]
```

So I've done this.

```
delm(A,B,C,D):-A>B,delm(B,A,C,D).
del1(1,[_|T],T):-!.
del1(N,[X|T],[X|L]):-N1 is N - 1,del1(N1,T,L).
delm(N,2,L,R):-del1(N,L,R),!.
delm(N,M,L,R):-M1 is M - 1,del1(N,L,Buf),delm(N,M1,Buf,R).
length([],0).
length([_|T],N):- length(T,N1),N is N1+1.
?-delm(2,4,[5,6,-3,6,11,56,81],L),write(L),nl.
```

But I also need to add that if one of the numbers is less than 1 or greater than the length of the list write the message ("Error"). So it should look like

```
?-delm(-2,4,[5,6,-3,6,11,56,81],L),write(L),nl.
"Error"
?-delm(2,-4,[5,6,-3,6,11,56,81],L),write(L),nl.
"Error"
?-delm(2,40,[5,6,-3,6,11,56,81],L),write(L),nl.
"Error"
```

I don't know how to do it. Please help!

Comment: Presumably you also want to produce "Error" if `A > B` - or is that ok? Edit: NM, I see you handled that in the first rule.

Comment: Do you want it to return 'Error' for L, or output it separately?

Comment: @Orbling I think for L, but is there any difference?

Comment: There is in the way you are calling it, as if you just output 'Error' and still call `write(L)`, while L is unbound, you'll get a nasty `_ABC` unbound term written.

Comment: @Orbling Ok, just output 'Error' I think, without nasty _ABC

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You only need to add a couple of rules, after the rule that checks that `A <= B`:

```
delm(A, _, _, 'Error') :- A < 1, !.
delm(_, B, C, 'Error') :- length(C, L), B > L, !.
```

So the entire code would be (just using your code):

```
del1(1,[_|T],T):-!.
del1(N,[X|T],[X|L]):-N1 is N - 1,del1(N1,T,L).

delm(A,B,C,D):-A>B,delm(B,A,C,D).
delm(A,_,_,'Error'):-A<1,!.
delm(_,B,C,'Error'):-length(C, L), B>L, !.
delm(N,2,L,R):-del1(N,L,R),!.
delm(N,M,L,R):-M1 is M - 1,del1(N,L,Buf),delm(N,M1,Buf,R).
```

Usually I would call such a routine `slice`.  Incidentally, [`length/2`](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?predicate=length/2) is usually built-in to most prolog environments.

Answer (score 1):

The "core" part of what you want could be implemented as follows:

```
:- use_module(library(clpfd)).

list_from_to_skipped(Xs,From,To,Ys) :-
   From   #=  From0 + 1,
   From   #=< To,
   N_Skip #=  To - From0,
   append(Prefix,Xs0,Xs),
   append(Skip,Suffix,Xs0),
   length(Prefix,From0),
   length(Skip,N_Skip),
   append(Prefix,Suffix,Ys).
```

Here is your sample query:

```
?- list_from_to_skipped([5,6,-3,6,11,56,81],2,4,Ls).
Ls = [5,11,56,81].
```

Now let's have a more general query:

```
?- list_from_to_skipped([a,b,c,d],From,To,Xs).
From = To, To = 1, Xs = [  b,c,d] ;
From = 1,  To = 2, Xs = [    c,d] ;
From = 1,  To = 3, Xs = [      d] ;
From = 1,  To = 4, Xs = [       ] ;
From = To, To = 2, Xs = [a,  c,d] ;
From = 2,  To = 3, Xs = [a,    d] ;
From = 2,  To = 4, Xs = [a      ] ;
From = To, To = 3, Xs = [a,b,  d] ;
From = 3,  To = 4, Xs = [a,b    ] ;
From = To, To = 4, Xs = [a,b,c  ] ;
false.
```